# Remover linhas de uma tabela Exvel com uma condição em VBA - Erro 424

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Só agora descobri o VBA e que pode melhorar muito as minhas ideias em Excel. Assim lancei-me a tentar fazer um inventário.
Fiz uma base de dados e pretendo retirar apenas a informação necessária para uma tabela.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWNfJ.png)
Nessa tabela quero eliminar linhas de acordo com uma certa condição Ex: *Diferente de Sala 2.*
Ao executar a macro dá **erro 424**.
[códigoVBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnWbn.png)    [Código do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF29Z.png)
Utilizei o código que vi num video e com ele funciona. Qual será o problema?

Answer (score -2):

Acrescente:

```
Option Explicit
```

ao início do módulo (primeira linha) e isto lhe economizará horas de sono. Acredito que a variável Activcell seja, em verdade, o objeto ActiveCell (faltou o "e"). Com o Option Explicit declarado, esse erro seria denunciado imediatamente pelo VBE.